# Parent Membership

Tags: wordpress, civimember

I have people that belong to multiple memberships,  However, if they belong to Membership 2 and Membership 1 expires, Membership 2 automatically expires as well.  Basically belong to Memberhip 2 is contingent upon Being in Membership 1.  Is there a way to program this automatically? or maybe an extention that takes care of this??

Membership 1 lasts one year and has a cost associated to it, and membership 2 is free and last 3 years, but is contingent upon Membership 1.

Thank you for any help given.

I Use wordpress 5.6 and CiviCRM 5.32

Comment: Maybe you elaborate a bit on the need of membership 2. Maybe you can doe the same with just a custom field on membership 1.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Contacts can belong to multimple memberships.  Once they become members of Membership type 1, they can select to become members of other groups, however if Membership one expires, the other meberships automiatically expire as well.  Only the top membership is paid, the others are free.

Comment: I am still not convinced of the need for an extra membership. My first try would be to create one (master) membership to record payments and membership statuses. On this membership, I would define a custom field called sub membership with a multi-select value for all groups. That does not create the problem of different expiration dates.